# Could not install package 'Portable PRISM - Windows Phone 8 1.0.1-rc'

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8, prism

I want to create an app for Windows Phone 8 using Prism library, I found that there is [Portable PRISM - Windows Phone 8 1.0.1-rc](http://nuget.org/packages/PortablePrism.WP8/) NuGet package available, but it failed to install with the following error:

install-package : Could not install package 'Portable.CommonServiceLocator 1.2.2'. You are 
trying to install this package into a project that targets 'WindowsPhone,Version=v8.0', but 
the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. 
For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package PortablePrism.Portable
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.Install 
   PackageCommand

Have anyone succeeded to install it? What could be the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: No downvote bro.  The problem is clearly stated in your question.  Portable PRISM has a dependency on Portable.CommonServiceLocator 1.2.2, which doesn't target WP8.  Therefore the install fails.  The only way to fix this is to 1. update the nuget installer for the common service locator to target WP8, which may require code changes, or 2. download the assemblies for both and add references to them manually, cutting nuget out of the process.  That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that my Nuget Package Manager was out of date, I've updated it to 2.6 and it just works fine (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/27077b70-9dad-4c64-adcf-c7cf6bc9970c)

Answer (score 0):

Try to update NuGet using the Visual Studio Extension Manager. 
Tools > Extension and Updates > Updates 
check for any updates.
If there is a new version of NuGet you will see it in the list of available updates.